# Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.2.5

Tags: android, android-studio

while i am trying to download build tools. an alert dialog open.
**All packages are not available for download!**

[image]

i am not getting what's the error.

Comment: Wrong version https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because there is no Build Tools revision **23.2.5**

See [Build tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html)

---

Just use the latest revision (currently **25.0.2**), In the root folder of your application project, find the `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    ...
}
```